# Power-Ups increasing projectile stats

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to increase the damage of the players fireball when a power up is picked up. I am getting an object reference error, I'm pretty sure this is due to the code being linked tot he player for the collision and the fireballs have their own script detailing their speed, damage etc.
Essentially I need a way to reference my fireball prefab (Called Bullet) so the code can access the 'damage' stat and increase it for a period of time.
**The code for the power-up is:-**

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Pickup(other);
        }
    }


    void Pickup(Collider2D player)
    {
        Instantiate(pickupEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);


        
        Fire stats = GetComponent<Fire>();
        stats.damage *= 2; 

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}

**The code for the fireball prefabs (known as Fire) is:-**

    

public class Fire : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator animator;
    public float speed = 20f;
    public int damage = 30;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public GameObject FireEmbers;
    public float liveTime = 1f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    
        {
       
        rb.velocity = transform.right * speed;
        }

   
    
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D hitInfo)
        
        {
        Enemy enemy = hitInfo.GetComponent<Enemy>();
        if (enemy != null)
        {
            enemy.TakeDamage(damage);
        }
        
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Instantiate(FireEmbers, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

    }

    void Update()
    {
        liveTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (liveTime <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            Instantiate(FireEmbers, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the error occuring?(What line)

Comment: You are trying to get a component that is not a part of a the gameobject, I assume. `Instantiate` returns the created object. Try using that to access the `Fire` script attached to your prefab.

Answer (score 0):

I actually resolved this by using scriptable objects instead of hard coding things into prefabs.